# php includes that correctly links href from wherever

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a block of html with hrefs. What i want to be able to do is only maintain one include file. Current code is:

```
<?php include __DIR__ . "/../../../includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

This links fine except any hrefs in the footer.php file must be prefaced by `../../../` due to the location. This means that I would have to create multiple footer files with different hrefs.

To display folder structure(*indicates where includes of the same php file are needed):

```
ROOT
¦
+---includes
¦   ¦
¦   +---footer.php
¦
¦
+---main
¦   ¦
¦   +---maps
¦       ¦
¦       +---uk
¦           ¦
¦           +---map.php*
¦
+---gallery.php*
¦
+---assets
    ¦
    +---icons
        +
        ¦
        +---facebook_1.png
```

Comment: You could use document root, something like this:
`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'directory/directory/file');`

Comment: Try to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/footer.php"` to access your footer file from your `map.php` and `gallery.php`

Comment: When you say, _“any hrefs in the footer.php file”_, you mean actual HTML links you are outputting there, right? Well the best way to handle that IMHO is to use URLs relative to the domain, starting with a slash.

Comment: unfortunately using both DOCUMENT_ROOTs as you have depicted does not include the file at all. & yes i mean html links. eg. <img src="../../../assets/icons/facebook_1.png"> and @CBroe that is exactly the behaviour i wish to employ, but it does not give me the image without using ../../../

Comment: So where in your folder structure is the `assets` folder located …?

Comment: @CBroe updated to include assets

Comment: `<img src="/assets/icons/facebook_1.png">`

Comment: @CBroe this is what i would expect to have to use with my limited knowledge, but does not work unless prefaced with ../../..

Comment: But your domain root is identical with ROOT in your structure shown above, right? Meaning, `http://yourdomain.tld/` mapes directly to ROOT (and then loads the index file from there, or sth. like that.)

Comment: _“unfortunately using both DOCUMENT_ROOTs as you have depicted does not include the file at all”_ - then please verify first of all what document root is actually set to.

Comment: @CBroe From MAMP folder looks like: MAMP > htdocs > radventures.co.uk (ROOT depicted in original post) > index.php

Comment: started looking into mamp conflicts. if i use HTTP_ROOT it links the file, but links are still firing from the location of the original.php doc, not the root.

Comment: looks like this is part of a more complex issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789816/how-to-set-the-document-root-and-site-root-in-my-local-php-dev-setup

Comment: i edited my document root in mamp. root is now where i thought it was. Links in included .php file still dont fire from root though!

Comment: _“root is now where i thought it was”_ - so it wasn’t before? Have you tried `/assets/icons/facebook_1.png` again after making the change?

Comment: it appears mamp hijacked the document_root and took it a folder up. i have tr

Comment: i have tried /assets/icons/facebook_1.png, but this does not point to root. i have also tried using href= "<?php echo ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/linkhere.html"; ?> , but this returns /Application/MAMP/htdocs/radventures.co.uk/linkhere.html

Comment: using  href= "<?php echo ($_SERVER['HTTP_ROOT'] . "/linkhere.html"; ?> gives desired behaviour!! but will this work once hosting for real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out. Mamp was confusing things and i had to include php in my link.

under MAMP>conf>apache>httpd.conf I changed my `DocumentRoot` to `"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/radventures.co.uk"` so it pointed to the root of my site.

Changeable document_root for mamp configuration:

```
<?PHP
  if ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/radventures.co.uk'){
    $root = 'HTTP_ROOT';
  }
  else {
    $root = 'DOCUMENT_ROOT';
  }
  $link = "$_SERVER[$root]";
?>
```

img link:

```
<img src="<?PHP echo ($link . "/assets/icons/facebook_1.png"); ?>
```

include:

```
<?PHP include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/footer.php"); ?>
```